# Xero API Token Handling

Tags: oauth-2.0, access-token, refresh-token, xero-api

We think we have a challenge with Xero tokens possibly due to how store and retreive the access and refresh token.

We have an application that seems to disconnect some tenants/Xero Organizations from time to time.  We are currently storing a single token (and using refresh and access tokens) without issue, but it feels like when a different user then authorizes a new tenant within our partner organziation, some of the previously authorized tenants stop working.

Do we need to maintain a new set of tokens per user who authorized the request?  E.g. User A has a set of Access+Refresh Tokens and User B has a set of Access + Refresh tokens?  If so, how do we keep track of what user has authorized which organization last?  E.g. if User A authorized Org1 and User B authorized Org2, but then User A also authorized Org2, when our app (per schedule) needs to access Org2 do we just have to enumerate all the tokens and call GetOrganizations() to determine which ones they have?

Again, we have been operating on the idea that a single Access + Refresh token is all we should work with despite working with 100's of tenants/Organizations.

Any great advice on the proper way to store and re-use tokens for Xero would be really appreciated.

We used to store tokens separately, but the combined into single token as it seemed correct, but we still seem to have a few issues, not sure if we need to store a token per user (e.g. decrypt the Access Token, the get User ID, and store 1 pair per unique user id (access+refresh).  Is this the proper way so that we don't have disconnect all the time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access tokens are issued per user per app. So user A would have one token pair for all the Xero organisations that they have authorised with your app and user B would have another pair for the organisations that they have authorised.

Storing 1 pair per user id would be a good idea.